# Android service startId parameter

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

So I understand the service lifecycle and all that. But I'm confused what the `startId` parameter is for?

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

I get that it's used in conjunction with `stopSelf(int)`, but I don't see what the point is or where the startId is being generated. What use case would using stopSelf(int) fall under?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What use case would using stopSelf(int) fall under?

Step #1: Call `startService()`

Step #2: Call `startService()` again

Step #3: Call `stopSelf()`

At this point, we want the service to not be stopped, since there is still work outstanding, represented by the second `startService()` call. We want the `startService()` and `stopSelf()` calls to match.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I think I'm overthinking this. So we would just store startId to a global variable whenever onStartCommand() gets executed, and then call stopSelf(int) on that global variable. Ok gotcha. I was trying to thinking about putting the IDs into a synchronous queue or something lol

Comment: @Falmarri: "So we would just store startId to a global variable whenever onStartCommand() gets executed" -- no, since there will be several of these. You may wish to examine `IntentService` and consider whether that is a better base class for you to use. It handles the `stopSelf(int)` calls itself, among other features.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess I'm still confused. How would you go about handling it yourself? Is there an example? I haven't seen any use of the startId in any examples

Comment: @Falmarri: You pass `startId` as a parameter around your code, until you get to the point where you need it for `stopSelf()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare how to manipulate the startId?? is there any way to control it, other than dealing with 1,2,3 etc?? is there any way to create instances of Service as a whole?

Comment: @CommonsWare do you mean we should not call stopSelf until all startService call does not finished. If this is the case could you explain how this can be handle ?

Comment: @CoDe: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain in greater detail what concerns you.

Comment: OK, I added my primary question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45339721/2624806). What I asked here in response of your answer, if we have call startService twice and so we should not call stopSelf till job not get done, how we can handle this? Does this make sense !